# What _L1 : _L2: mean?

Tags: java, android, logic, conditional-statements

hi  i have decompiled an android project but i dont know what this part mean 
please help with example code. what does _L1 _L2 do ?
tanks

```
i = 0;
_L5:
    if (i < AnswerTexts.size()) goto _L2; else goto _L1
_L1:
    j = 0;
_L6:
    if (j < AnswerTexts.size()) goto _L4; else goto _L3
_L3:
    k = 0;
_L7:
    if (k >= SuggestionTexts.size())
    {
        return;
    }
    break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_2107;
_L2:
    ((ImageView)AnswerTexts.get(i)).setVisibility(0);
    ((ImageView)AnswerBackground.get(i)).setVisibility(0);
    i++;
    setVisible()
      goto _L5
_L4: and so on ...
```

Comment: like the goto suggests, these are labels.

Comment: Labels. Search for goto statement...

Comment: This `spagetti code` is a **typical decompiler output**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These `_L1:`, `_L2:`, etc denote labels. They are essentially markers in your code at which the runtime might decide to shift its execution. For instance, a loop can be defined as:

```
int x = 0
Label1:
if (x < 10) {
    ...
    x++;
    goto Label1
}
```

This would be similar to:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    ...
}
```

When writing code, developers should avoid using labels since they could make your code behave erratically or unpredictably.